# Uninstall after sudo pip3 install doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, uninstallation

I am working on an python package which supports pip3 installation.
Therefore I have written an appropriate setup.py file, including some tests and doc.

Now when I install the package in editable mode with

```
pip3 install --user -e .
```

the files are keeped where they are, a directory xyz.egg-info is created in the current (source directory) and a file

```
xyz.egg-link
```

is created under /home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/.

That's fine! Uninstall using

```
pip3 uninstall xyz
```

called from the source directory (where also the directory xyz.egg-info is located) also works fine.

But when I try to install the package globally under /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ using pip3 I have to call it as sudo:

```
sudo pip3 install -e .
```

And when I try to uninstall the package with

```
sudo pip3 uninstall xyz
```

I get the following error:

```
Can't uninstall 'xyz'. No files were found to uninstall.
```

Although there is a file xyz.egg-link created under:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/
```

Can anyone explain me why this doesn't work?

Thanks and regards,
Daniel.

Comment: which version of pip are you using?

Comment: I am using: pip 9.0.1

Comment: Can you post the contents of your setup.py file? If it doesn't contain any files, that's what pip will state.

Comment: It's all in my github repro: https://github.com/dstrigl/htheatpump?files=1

Comment: Are there any faults in my setup.py?

Comment: Additional info: If I call the installation not in editable mode (without '-e') deinstallation also works fine. Therefore it only fails in editable mode!